# Session Variable not working in Internet Explorer, but works fine in Firefox / Chrome

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer

We've developed a web app with Asp.Net MVC 3 using Razor pages.

In the page we're having problems with a user selects items from a menu and they're added to the order details pane on the right of the page, where multiple items of the same type are totaled up e.g. 3 x Garlic Bread etc.

To do this we add to a list of T and store it in a session variable as in the following code:

```
List<MunuItems> OrderItems = HttpContext.Session["_OrderItems"] as List<MunuItems>;

MunuItems newItem = new MunuItems();
// Set the newItem values

OrderItems.Add(newItem);
// Add the list to the session
HttpContext.Session.Add("_OrderItems", OrderItems);
// Retrun the partial view
return PartialView("_OrderItems", OrderItems);
```

This all works fine in Firefox or Chrome, but when I try this in Internet Explorer 8 / 9 the behavior is all over the place. Only 1 of each item can be added, trying to add 2nd items can cause other items to drop off the list etc.

You can view the page here http://software.ayslive.com/WR_TakeAway/menu

Can anyone suggest how this can be fixed in Internet Explorer or why it's not working in IE?

Comment: Sounds like something else is wrong because the Session is independent of the browser (it is stored on the server).

Answer (score 1):

It appears as though you are using ajax somewhere.

It is quite possible that you are using the 'GET' method and that it is cached.  If so try `cache: false` in your ajax call (the default is true).

Comment: Thanks, yes we are using Ajax to call a partial view. Can you tell me where I place the cache: false?

Comment: you should have a call like so: `$.ajax({ url: 'your_url', type: 'GET', cache: false})` (GET is also the default type).

Comment: oh, I see you are using 'unobtrusive ajax' --- you will need to see how to get it to *not* cache.

Comment: You could also try `$.ajaxSetup({ cache:false });` somewhere up-front to change the global ajax settings.

Comment: Hi, yes I'm using Asp.Net MVC Razor pages. The call is    @Ajax.ActionLink("Add to order", "AddOrderItem", new { ID = Item.id },
                  new AjaxOptions
                  {
                      UpdateTargetId = "_Orders",
                      InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace

                  })

Comment: Eben, thanks for your help. I've figured out how to do it from your reply, have change the method to Post. Will update the answer to this tomorrow

Comment: That should also get the job done since POST can not be cached.  Glad you managed!