# Session Variables in IE

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, internet-explorer-9, session-variables

Searched, but couldn't find a good answer.

I have an `ASP.NET` application that I am developing. I'm using session variables within the app.

In `Firefox` & `Chrome`, they all work.
But in `IE` (ver 9), there's one variable that's not working. I'm not sure if it's a storage or a retrieval (or both) at this point. The variable in question that I'm storing is a List(T) type. It's the only one of it's kind that I'm using. Can't help but think there's a correlation there.

One other old post mentioned the possibility that cache is causing the problem, but I didn't understand the answer very well.

P.S. If possible, please post any code samples in `VB`. Sometimes I can read the `C#` and translate it, and sometimes not.

```
Dim Rec_IDs As New List(Of String)
Rec_IDs = Session("Rec_IDs")
and
       Dim Rec_IDs As New List(Of String)
        Dim Rec_ID As Int32
        Rec_IDs = Session("Rec_IDs")
        For Each Row As GridViewRow In gvParts.Rows
            If CType(Row.FindControl("chkSelect"), CheckBox).Checked Then
                Rec_ID = gvParts.DataKeys(Row.RowIndex).Value
                If Not Rec_IDs.Contains(Rec_ID) Then
                    Rec_IDs.Add(Rec_ID)
                End If
                CType(Row.FindControl("chkSelect"), CheckBox).Checked = False
            End If
        Next
Session("Rec_IDs") = Rec_IDs
lblCount.Text = String.Format("You have {0} records selected", Rec_IDs.Count.ToString)
```

Other answer: [Session Variable not working in Internet Explorer, but works fine in Firefox / Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020330/session-variable-not-working-in-internet-explorer-but-works-fine-in-firefox-c)

Comment: Could you please show your code?  Also, can you add a link to the post that you think answered your question but you don't understand the solution?

Comment: @jadarnel27 - OK, I edited my post and took out the word unacceptably.  Anything else?

Comment: @SteveWellens I fully agree with the rest of your comment =)  This should have nothing to do with the browser, unless the browser is causing the data to not make it to the server to be captured in a session variable for some reason.  Still, not nearly enough information to know either way.

Comment: I edited your post to unjumble your code. It has to be peer reviewed though. You may want to do that if you see this before my edit's approved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check your cookies are enabled or not in your browser. If the cookies are blocked that will be the problem with `IE`

Also have a look at

[Cookieless ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx), 
[ASP.NET State Management Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s.aspx),[Difference between browser session and asp.net session](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/asp-net/17/10303311/difference-between-browser-session-and-aspnet-session.aspx)

Comment: Cookies are allowed, besides all cookies are working EXCEPT 1.

Comment: Marking this as accepted because it was the best answer for the question. However, turns out the question was wrong.

Comment: Btw, just for anyone reading this later. It wasn't the session variable that was the issue. It was the code variable populating the session variable that was was the issue (and still is, but I put that into another post so as to not confuse things).